# How to iterate this Go interface

Tags: json, go

Here is a sample of my JSON post:

```
{
    "jsonFilter" :[{
        "column": "",
        "contains": "",
        "condition": "",
        "not": true
    }, {
        "column": "",
        "contains": "",
        "condition": "",
        "not": true
    }]
}
```

My Echo framework handler:

```
func GetFilteredFileData(c echo.Context) error {
    body := echo.Map{}
    if err := c.Bind(&body); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(body)

    for key, element := range body {
        fmt.Println(key, element)
    }
}
```

Results:

```
jsonFilter [map[column:StartTimestamp condition:contains contains:<nil> not:false] map[column:SourceIP condition:startsWith contains:<nil> not:true]]
```

This is not index accessible, nor key accessible. I was told I needed to make a struct or 2, but all my efforts there did not work (gorilla schema, json.Marshal, etc)

What is the proper way to take this map and make it actually usable in a variable/struct ref?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unmarshal that json into the following struct:

```
type Body struct {
  Filter []JSONFilter `json:"jsonFilter"`
}

type JSONFilter struct {
   Column string `json:"column"`
   Contains string `json:"contains"`
   Condition string `json:"condition"`
   Not bool `json:"not"`
}
```

I don't know about this echo framework, but it looks like something like this should work:

```
    body := Body{}
    if err := c.Bind(&body); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

Or, `json.Unmarshal`, if the above doesn't do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is it! `{[{StartTimestamp  contains false} {SourceIP  startsWith true}]}` is my new result. I'm still new to Go, you wouldn't perhaps know how to iterate over this would you, since it's wrapped in an Object?

Comment: Are you iterating over the jsonfilter part? If so, `for index.jf:=range body.Filter { ... }`

Comment: This is amazing, you've been a great help, thank you!